# azure openai gpt-35-turbo does not answer Chinese prompt in Chinse

Tags: chatgpt-api, azure-openai

I am trying the chat playground for azure openai. I have uploaded two documents, one English and one Chinese. I found that it can answer English to my english doc. However, it cannot answer Chinese when I type Chinese question. How should I configure it to let it answer in Chinese?